# JPA delete invalid

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-data-jpa

JPA a thing has statements for insert table A, statements for delete table B, and statements for insert and delete are printed in the log, but sometimes both insert and delete take effect, sometimes an insert takes effect, a delete does not take effect, the entire method is error-free and the insert and delete statements are printed

The code is as follows

```
// 入库
cmsCa.setExpirationDate(new Date());
cmsCa.setDeleted(true);
CmsCaCanceled cmsCaCanceled = cmsCaMapper.convertToCmsCaArchive(cmsCa);

cmsCaArchiveRepository.save(cmsCaCanceled);
cmsCaRepository.delete(cmsCa);

CmsCaOperationLog cmsCaOperationLog = CmsCaOperationLog.build(CERT_OPER_CANCEL, cmsCa, true);
cmsCaOperationLogRepository.save(cmsCaOperationLog);
```

The save method was successful, delete was unsuccessful, and no error was reported

My guess is that the JPA automatic update is related to the simultaneous execution of the delete, but the set statement also has this problem

Answer (score 0):

I looked at my log printouts and found that shortly after I deleted, an insert statement appeared. Looking at the contents of the log, I found that there was a Sava statement somewhere else, it was not deleted at first, and then it was saved. JPA's save method is insert if the data does not exist, and update if the data exists